# How to restrict customer access from app back-end in shopify

Tags: node.js, shopify

I'm trying to add a feature in a shopify app that blocks a certain customer from accessing a certain product, but I found out that I can block access from the site's theme. But how can I control customer access from an app and not from the theme, or is there a way I can edit the theme using an app's backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assets api to modify theme files. You could use this to update a snippet that contains your logic and then process the layout to make sure the snippet is included.

Comment: But that is highly NOT recommended as when uninstalling the App, the merchant is stuck with a template full of junk that will be hard to clean.

Comment: It's about the only way to do it that I can think of and addresses the OP's question. The other option is to do something in the theme directly without the app. At least the app could have a control panel where if it is made inactive it could clean itself up. Store owner would have to be warned to make it inactive before uninstalling it.

Comment: Often the only way to do something is terrible. We learned early on how bad it can be when you open a merchant's templates, stick crap in there to achieve some minor goals, and then the merchant decides to go in a different direction. Now they have a potential disaster as the template contains orphaned bad code.

If the OP is asking for a bad pattern, why give it to them, instead give them the safer more recommended pattern?

Comment: Do you have one? BTW IMO this is not terrible unless the merchant acts impulsively or the developer doesn't communicate a clean up strategy. It would easily let the merchant change or update their theme and the app would just re-install the filter code. But if you have a better strategy please share it.